# How fast is RecursiveDirectoryIterator and Zip Archive?

Tags: php, php-ziparchive, recursiveiterator

So I wanna zip a folder using RecursiveDirectoryIterator, how fast can it zip up a very complicated directory, with all the files combined together not more than 600 MB of size?

This is the code am using:

```
$mainFolder=basename($routeFolder);
if(!file_exists('../zips'))
    mkdir('../zips', 0744);

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$firstres=$zip->open($zipName, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($routeFolder),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file) {

    if(is_file($file) && file_exists($file)){
        $new_filename = substr($file, strpos($file, $mainFolder));
        $zip->addFile($file,$new_filename);
    }
}

$zip->close();
```

So, approximately, how long is it gonna take to zip up a very complex directory? Is it gonna face any memory issue? Anyway, am using ajax, so it wont lead to browser crashing or browser page becoming unresponsive...but still how long is it gonna take?

Comment: It's as fast as your server will execute it. But as my servers aren't the same as your server, how can you expect anybody other than yourself to know how long it will take?

Comment: Have you tried seeing how long it takes on your server? The only way to know is to actually run it and see for yourself.

Comment: Uhhh...okay!! Thanx got the answer :) But just assume a mediocre server...is there any estimate...approx? @MarkBaker ... and right now am using a free host for testing purpose, so i can't create a very complex directory of 500 MB due to limitations, so I was just asking!

Comment: WIth so many dependencies.... disk speed, processor memory, server load, etc.... even an estimate on a different server will be meaningless.

Comment: However, if timeout is a real concern, then you don't do a task like this as a browser request.... you submit the request to a back-end process that will email the zip file when it's completed

Comment: What i wanted to know, like it shouldn't take more than 15 minutes right ? Keeping all of these in mind? OR can it? Like if the server and the tools are too poor? @MarkBaker (sorry for being noob)

Comment: Yes am using ajax for this! @MarkBaker Thankyou!! :) So am using, _url: download.php_ and once the zip is done, that is in the _success: function(){}_ am starting the download. So the _success: function(){}_ is gonna run once the zip is done forming right ?

Comment: If you can't return a response to a user in <15 seconds, then you shouldn't be handling that request via the web service, but as a back-end process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69589/discussion-between-bayblade567-and-mark-baker).